# Compiler Error C2664 or C2731 C++ 2015

Tags: c++, winapi, directx

I have been able to fine the `WinMain` function. Now I'm trying to make a `win32` app:

```
#include <Windows.h>
int WINAPI WinMain() {
    MessageBox(NULL,"Test", "Hello World", NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

and then I get error `C2731`.

Comment: what is the error message?

Comment: Please edit your question to include the actual errors, complete and unedited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't provided any parameters to the WinMain() method, and the error C2731 is saying that this method [cannot be overloaded](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x7t11wke.aspx).

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633559(v=vs.85).aspx):

```
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance,
               HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
               LPSTR lpCmdLine,
               int nCmdShow);
```

Error C2664 is most likely your call to MessageBox, so try changing to something like:

```
MessageBox(NULL, L"Test", L"Hello World", NULL);
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out I wasn't useint main.cpp as my main source code file and my WinMain needed to be switched to wWinMain

Comment: None of this makes any sense. There is no such thing as a main source code file. All source files are compiled to object code, and the linker assembles the object code into an executable image. [Michael McMullin's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33011984/1889329) outlines the real issues.